# How to achieve url maxtry filter in apache tomcat

Tags: apache, filter

Any one please give me some ideas to achieve maxtry concept.

I want to destroy the url path after some amount of access.

For eg., if I give maxtry = 2 for the run time generated url (http://localhost:8080/Club/dely/ios/item/42/23/cc.mp4), After the two times access of the above url for the third time that url path will not be able to access for anyone.

How to achieve this using apache filter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone please give some ideas?